# API Management virtual network object

Tags: azure-api-management

I am learning how to create an APIM instance using Powershell using the steps give here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Here at one point they talk about creating a API Management virtual network object.

What exactly is API Management virtual network object ?

Comment: You can create azure virtual network and provide its details as an object to deploy the apim service to the VNET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK,

**Within the Network, to access backend services - Azure APIM Instance should be deployed in an Azure Virtual Network**.

So, you would be creating the Virtual Network, subnets in that created VNet, NSGs, NSG rules for the Application Gateway, etc.

When you attach the above details (VNet, SubNet Data) in an object to the APIM Instance/Service, it can be known as **APIM Virtual Network Object**.